# Align basis of vector space with that of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose I have two real vector spaces $V,S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $S\subset V$. Say the dimension of $V$ is $l$ and that of $S$ equals $m<l$. They are given in terms of their basis vectors $v_i, i=1,\ldots,l$ and $s_i,i=1,\ldots,m$ (as results of the computation of the nullspace of two related homogeneous systems). I want to find a new basis of $V$ such that it reads $\{s_i\mid i=1,\ldots,m\}\cup \{w_i\mid i=m+1,\ldots,l\}$. In other words: how can I systematically compute $w_i,i=m+1,\ldots,l$, which are linearly independent of the basis of $S$. Naively, I would simply solve the linear system $v_i=a_1 s_1 + \cdots + a_m s_m$ for each $v_i$ and discard it (as a basis vector of $V$) if this homogeneous system has a non-trivial solution (to see if it is linearly independent). The set of discarded vectors would then be replaced by the basis of $S$. But, since the algorithm is to be implemented in a computer code, I wonder if this is the most clever solution and if there are flaws. Note that numerical stability is not an issue here. The basis vectors shall all have integer elements.

Answer (score 2):

You should not solve that linear system involving only the vectors $s_i$. Instead you should check that each candidate vector for $w_k$ is linearly independent of $s_1,\ldots,s_m$ **and** $w_1,\ldots,w_{k-1}$. Only then is it ensured that the vectors retained form a basis. Given this modification the method is sound.

From a practical point of view, you might want to replace the vectors $s_1,\ldots,s_m,w_1,\ldots,w_{k-1}$, maybe only for use in the test, by another sequence of vectors that span the same subspace, but are in echelon form: for each vector there is a coordinate position (its pivot position) where it is the last in the sequence to have a nonzero entry. Then for any candidate vector $v_i$, you first clear, from left to right for the vectors already in the sequence, the coordinate of $v_i$ that is in its pivot position (by adding a multiple of that vector). After all these coordinates have been cleared the new vector, as well as the original $v_i$, is linearly independent of the retained vectors if (and only if) the new vector is nonzero. If this is the case $v_i$ can be retained, and the new vector is ready to join the vectors in echelon form, with the position of any chosen non-zero entry (for instance the first one) as its pivot position.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I think I was not clear enough. $w_i$ were supposed to be elements of the basis of $V$ (those $v_i$ which are not linearly dependent on $s_i$; i.e. $w_i$ are already linearly independent). Our approaches should therefore be equivalent, or not?

Comment: You keep missing the point of my first paragraph: **it does not suffice** (except for the first one) that the $v_i$ you retain be linearly independent on the $s_i$, they should be linearly independent on the $s_i$ **together with the previously retained** vectors $v_i$.

Comment: And the approach I sketched in the second paragraph already takes into account your wish to make a basis consisting of the $s_i$ together with some of the $v_i$. After considering $v_i$, clearing its coordinates at pivot postions, and testing it to be nonzero (therefore linearly independent), you can retain the _original_ value of $v_i$ in the basis. It is just that for efficiency reasons it is useful to hold, locally, a second (echelon) basis, with pivots, to quickly perform the linear independence test. If $v_i$ is retained in the basis, the modified $v_i$ can go into the echelon basis.

Comment: Now I see your point. Seemingly my linear algebra is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Gram-Schmidt algorithm, with the basis vectors of $S$ as your first $m$ inputs.  You will end up with $l-m$ zero vectors, but just discard them.

Comment: **No**. Gram-Schmidt is for making a basis orthogonal, and this question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Yes, agreed, it does not meet my question, but in fact an orthogonal basis could have advantages for my application. But, would the the non-zero orthogonal vectors be indeed linearly independent of ${s_i}$, the basis of $S$. In principle I am flexible also to change the basis of S to one which is orthogonal.

Comment: I might have slightly misunderstood the question; you actually just want a subset of your initial set of vectors $\{s_i\}\cup\{v_i\}$?  You can still use Gram-Schmidt; just keep track of which indices give you non-zero answers, and at the end, go back and keep the corresponding vectors in your original set.  Marc's suggestion is probably more efficient though.

Comment: I need a basis of $V$ which contains the given basis of $S$ as subset. Alternatively the basis of $S$ may be transformed into a new basis of $S$ (possibly orthogonal). In this case I need a basis of $V$ which contains the transformed basis of $S$ as subset.