# Extension of Wahba’s problem with infinite weights

Tags: matrices, geometry, optimization, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

[Wahba's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahba%27s_problem) seeks to find a $3 \times 3$ orthonormal rotation matrix that minimizes

$$ J(\mathbf{R}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^{N} a_k\| \mathbf{w}_k - \mathbf{R} \mathbf{v}_k \|^2 $$

I want to solve a version of this for $N \in \{2,3\}$ and weights $\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} = \infty$. The geometrical interpretation of this is to form a rotation matrix to maximally align $w_1$ to $v_1$, then rotate about that vector to maximally align $w_2$ with $v_2$. If $w_3$ and $v_3$ are provided, then they have an effective weight of 0 and the solution is unchanged.

In [this scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/17462) I lay out an algorithm to solve this exactly on SO(3):

1. Create orthonormal frames from the base and reference unit vectors.

```
# Do the below for R_w and R_v
w_3 = np.cross(w_1, w_2)
w_2 = np.cross(w_3, w_1)
R_w = Rotation.from_matrix([w_1, w_2, w_3])
```

2. Compute the rotation between them, eg: `R = R_w * R_v.inv()`

I believe it shouldn't be too hard to extend this method to higher dimensions as well. Is there a name for this problem/solution? I doubt I'm the first one to think about it.

Comment: $\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} = \infty$ is meaningless ; maybe you mean $\frac{a_k}{a_{k+1}} \to \infty$ when $k \to \infty$.

Comment: My notation there may be off, but hopefully the idea is clear. I want to give infinite preference to aligning the smallest $k$, then given that constraint give infinite preference to aligning the next smallest $k$, etc. (Well, for my example, you'd stop there.) $k \to \infty$ does not play a role here.

Comment: Perhaps a clearer way of putting it is $\frac{a_k+1}{a_k} = \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching I found this described as an "align-constrain" process in [Magner, "Extending Target Tracking Capabilities through Trajectory and Momentum Setpoint Optimization", 2018](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4112&context=smallsat), but am having trouble finding an original source, a generalization to higher dimensions, or a previous connection to Whaba's problem. This seems like a fairly fundamental problem to kinematics, so I'd be surprised if it doesn't have earlier roots.

Update: After more searching, I believe this is best thought of as using [the Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) to orthogonalize the two sets of vectors as desired here, and the rotation matrix can be formed as above. For higher dimensions, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347358/align-basis-of-vector-space-with-that-of-subspace) has a more rigorous procedure. Solved, unless someone has another name for this!

Comment: The relationship here has been formalized and implemented into scipy's `align_vectors` method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors.html